# Expanding branches of a family tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

I'm making a family tree. The following script allows the user to expand branches of the tree. It works fine, but there must be a better way.

You can see it working [here](http://www.nicholsonfamilytree.co.uk/test1.asp).

```
$(function(){
    $('.oc').prepend('<img src="icons/bullet_add.png" alt="more" width="16" height="16"/>')
    $("ul[id|=Nested]").hide();
    $("a[id|=trigger_Nested]").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).siblings("ul");
        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown("fast");
            $(this).next("span").html('<img src="icons/bullet_take.png" alt="close" width="16" height="16" />');     
        } else {
            text.slideUp("fast");
            $(this).next("span").html('<img src="icons/bullet_add.png" alt="more" width="16" height="16" />');     
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes:

1. I would use classes instead of ids for the nested links. I don't know if it's faster to search the DOM for all elements with a specific class, but it looks cleaner and doesn't require you to create unique ids for each element:

   ```
   $('a.nested-trigger').click(...);
   ```
2. I would also use classes for the icons, as it's less expensive than replacing DOM nodes:

   HTML:

   ```
   <span class="oc collpased"></span>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```
   .oc {
     position: relative;
     right: 10px;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 16px;
     height: 16px;
   }
   .collapsed {
     background: url(icons/bullet_add.png);
   }
   .expanded {
     background: url(icons/bullet_take.png);
   }
   ```

   JS:

   ```
   $(this).next("span").removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
   ```
3. This is related more to the UX of your demo but I would make the icons themselves clickable as well, because they're big enough to look like buttons, and they overlap part of the node.

Comment: All very good points.  I especially agree with seand's 3rd point.  I tried to click the icons and was thinking the whole thing didn't work for a second.